# HttpURLConnection with server redirections

Tags: android, redirect, httpurlconnection

i'm trying to get the source code from a site using this code

```
        conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(20000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        int response = conn.getResponseCode();
        if (response = 307){
            String locationHeader = conn.getHeaderField("Location");
            URL redirectURL = new URL(locationHeader);
            ...
        }
```

when the server responds with a 307 code i create a new connection with the same parameters as above with the new url given by the server.
this code works fine while following the first 2 redirects, at the third the server gives a relative url that forces a MalformedURLException when my code executes ' new URL(locationHeader); '.

so i tried to fix that adding the ' http://*servername*/ ' to the ' locationHeader ' string but doing that creates a loop cause the server then redirects to the first url of his redirection chain.
since my browser gets the source code from that server with no problems is there a way to achieve that with HttpURLConnection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if someone is interested thanks to Fiddler i worked out a solution to this issue.
first i changed the "User-Agent" property to mimic the one of Mozilla then i manually tweaked the cookie the serer was sending in its reply with the relative path.
that did the trick. thank you Fiddler.